# Creating a loess model in R using only preceding points in a time-series

Tags: r, time-series, loess

I want to be able to create a loess model that fits only the local PRECEDING points in a time series, so it does not use information from the future in the fit.

I would like to know it it is supported, or if the is any other function to perform this.
I have tried using the subset parameter, but it seems static, and not suited for what I want.

Comment: You can try to use `embed` to format your data in an autoregressive way, then fit it.

Comment: You're not clear on what you want.  `for(j in 1:N) loess(data[1:j])` looks like the basis for your work. Or, replace `1:N` with whatever collection of indices you want to work with.

Comment: Loess selects some local, near data point for doing the local fiting that is part of it. I want to be able to tell the function to only select data before it. Howerer, I want this to be only a single fit, not some multiple fits each with its data window.

Comment: I don't think that's how any fitting function works.  Sans data on both sides of the value of interest, you can't get an (unambiguous) differentiable curve.